# Accessing session variables from WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

Is it possible to access session variables (and their values) from a webview control in Android?

I searched the documentation but found nothing.

Answer (score -1):

You can sync webview session cookis like this

```
public static void sync(String url) {
         List<Cookie> cookies=null;
        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        if (cookieManager == null)
            return;

        RFC2109Spec cookieSpec = new RFC2109Spec();
        String rawCookieHeader = null;
        try {
            URL parsedURL = new URL(url);
            rawCookieHeader = cookieManager.getCookie(parsedURL.getHost());
            if (rawCookieHeader == null)
                return;
            int port = parsedURL.getPort() == -1 ? parsedURL.getDefaultPort()
                    : parsedURL.getPort();

            CookieOrigin cookieOrigin = new CookieOrigin(parsedURL.getHost(),
                    port, "/", false);
            cookies = cookieSpec.parse(new BasicHeader("set-cookie",
                    rawCookieHeader), cookieOrigin);

            System.out.println("Session Cookis : " + cookies);

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
```

**How to call? From webview**

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                sync(url);
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            }
        });
```

Comment: But i am storing a variable in session. Not a cookie.

Comment: I am not seeing my session variables, only my cookies :(

Comment: I think you want to login through webview and same session to use with android httpclient

Comment: No, I want to read a session variable I am using in my website, so I can make a decission in the native webview control. Nothing related to login or authentication.

Comment: just give me your website url I will try and let you know how it is possible.

Comment: I cant, it's not live yet

Comment: MichelReap, May i know have you got solution for your problem statement because now my problem statement is also same.